# Laravel 5 token mismatch on Post from remote connection

Tags: laravel, exception, post, token, mismatch

Searched for a whole day and couldn't find an answer
I'm running my server with `php artisan serve -host:0.0.0.0` so I could communicate with my server remotly.
When I test on my localhost everything works fine, but when I try to send a post request from a remote device it's responding with a TokenMismatchException.
debuged this alittle furter and sew that the token I'm sending via

```html
    <meta name="_token" id="token-input" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}"/>
```

```js
function getToken(){
    return $('#token-input').attr('content');
}

//angular ajax
$http.post('/store', {id: 1,
            '_token': getToken()}).
            then(function (response) {
                ...
            },
            function (response) {
                $('body').html(response.data);
            });
```

remains the same while my session token is constantly changing.
tested it by changing VerifyCsrfToken.php handle method to throw

```
$token1 = $request->input('_token') ?: $request->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN');
throw new \App\Exceptions\SaleSiteException('token= ' . $token1 . '\nsession_token= ' . $request->session()->token());
```

I'm using the 'files' driver. tried to change my priviliges to framework/sessions folder but no luck there.
by the way, sending get request works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

$.ajaxSetup({
     headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

The documentation can be found [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#csrf-protection).